# Predict Probabilities for top N classes on validation data

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

I am working on text classification. I have converted my text in to vectors. I have multiple classes. I am getting 80% accuracy with my XGB Classifier model. I want to get probabilities of top 3 classes, so when I pass the new data I should get 3 prediction along with probability.

My classes are categorical , so I am using label encoder for the same. Below is my code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
le = LabelEncoder()
y_train_le = le.fit_transform(y_train)
xgb_cl = XGBClassifier().fit(X_train,y_train_le)
pred_prob = xgb_cl.predict_proba(X_test)
pred = [dict(zip(le.classed_, cs)) for cs in pred_prob]
```

With the above code I am getting dictionary with class and its respective probability. How can I predict the top 3 classes when I give a new data? Also, when i do prediction on Test data, I can get top 3 probabilities against the actual class for validation.

Comment: I think you should try and state the question clearer. How can you predict? with a model. Please clarify a bit so you can get better help.

Comment: @Quant1892387 - I want to predict the probability of top 3 classes rather than predicting the single class.

Comment: look into regr_multirf.predict instead of predict_proba. Maybe that can help. You are using the wrong model for what you want. I think. And if you can force using, I believe the outcomes might be independent.